# Numero random de 2 cifras en javascript

Tags: javascript, random

tengo una duda, estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual cuando el usuario olvida su contraseña, se le generará una aleatoria al introducir su usuario, es una prueba.

Tengo echo esto: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 99)) + 1;`

Quiero generar un numero random entre 1 y 99 pero que sea positivo, ya que aveces me genera un numero negativo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En esa publicacion explican que la formula para un numero aleatorio en un rango es `Math.random() * (max - min) + min;`